# Web element with same name and xpath under two elements in the navigation pane

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I have 2 web elements with the same XPath and name but under the different navigation links. Both links point to the same page but with a different title. How should I access each of the links uniquely?

I am a beginner to python selenium programming

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the question itself. You must try identifying the elements using title with combination of other attributes if they have unique titles.

PS: Please(always) add the code you have tried and the relevant(in this case HTML) required files/snippet which can help us understand and investigate better. Questions with enough information get faster replies :)